# simple form symfony2 firewall redirection

Tags: security, symfony, authentication, firewall

Here is my issue.

**Situation**:

I am trying to add some custom logic during user login. I could find to ways to do so:
hard way (but with a lot of control); building my own authentication provider, following [this guidelines of the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) or [this complementing publication of vandenbrand](http://blog.vandenbrand.org/2012/06/19/symfony2-authentication-provider-authenticate-against-webservice/)

easy way (exactly what I need ): use simple_form. simple_form is a key which has the same options as form_login, but for which I can define an "authenticator".
[cookbook tuto I used can be found here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html)

**Issue**

I had an existing and operational app/security.yml configuration with 'form_login' key.

```
secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/foo/user/secured/
        form_login:
            check_path: /foo/user/secured/login_check
            login_path: /foo/user/login
```

I followed steps of the tutorial described above. therefore, my security.yml gets modified to:

```
        secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/foo/user/secured/
        #form_login:
        simple_form:
            authenticator: foo_authenticator
            check_path: /foo/user/secured/login_check
            login_path: /foo/user/login
```

when I try to access a page /foo/user/secured/target of the secured area, the firewall does its job: it catches the query and asks for credentials (via intermediary page /foo/user/login).

However, once right credentials input (and obviously validated), I keep staying on the same page. It does not redirect to the page /foo/user/secured/target I was asking for in the first place. There is no refreshing to trying to go to that page via new request: I remain stuck at login stage.

EDIT 1: here are the steps I identify based on logs and debugging:

1) user tries to access /foo/user/secured/target, for which you need to be identified at least with ROLE_USER to access

2) firewall intercepts this request, as it matches listened routes (app/config/security.yml):

```
secured_area:
pattern:    ^/foo/user/secured/
```

3) it redirects toward login route

4) user fills in with username and password, and submits post

5) when form is received, a token gets created by createToken method of custom authenticater. It returns an object of class UsernamePasswordToken created with parameter username, password in clear, authenticater key: UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $providerKey)

6) token gets passed onto authenticateToken method de of authenticater object. this method compares clear password hash contained in token andd accessed through $token->getCredentials()) with hashed password in database.

7) authentication worked: we get redirected toward  /foo/user/secured/target . token and user get serialized in session (**ISSUE STARTS HERE: indeed, user clear password is erased so that it doesn't leave tracks in session, and getCredentials() will return empty string now**).

8) while loading page, le firewall is activated. It detects user logged in, seems to want to check its token. Therefore, it calls authenticateToken.

9) authenticateToken tries to compare sha1($token->getCredentials()) to hashed password in database. comme $token->getCredentials() is empty, comparison fails. authenticateToken raises an exception.

10) raised exception triggers firewall redirection toward login page. There we are: stuck in infinite loop landing systematically on login page.

STOP EDIT 1.

**Solution**

Does anyone know why this change of behaviour between 'form_login' and 'simple_form'? Most of all, would you know a good way to fix this ? I guess authenticate method or custom authenticater should be slightly changed, but I am not yet confident enough with security to solve this elegantly.

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Wisebes

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some string (not the object) from sample. Or implement __toString() for User entity.

**NOT**
return new UsernamePasswordToken($user, ...

**USE**
return new UsernamePasswordToken($user->getEmail() or whatever, ...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access to the page you was requesting, you could use any of the options that Symfony offers to you:

Redirecting after Login:

- always_use_default_target_path (type: Boolean, default: false)
- default_target_path (type: string, default: /)
- target_path_parameter (type: string, default: _target_path)
- use_referer (type: Boolean, default: false)

You could see the section of the book 'SecurityBundle Configuration ("security")'
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

I hope that this be useful for you.

Kind regards.

Comment: Hi Airam. Thanks for the feedback. However, I do know these options, but they have no impact on my issue. using default option set, We normaly get redirected toward page asked in the first place. However, we currently are not. even if I set 'default_target_path' to /foo/user/secured/target , I keep stuck on the login page (!)

Comment: In log :                                                     `[2014-04-30 17:27:59] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener::onKernelException". [] []
[2014-04-30 17:27:59] security.INFO: Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point (Invalid username or password) [] []` .  curious thing is, this notification happens at reload time, after the user was authenticated successfully: `[2014-04-30 17:17:30] security.INFO: User "13987806178942" has been authenticated successfully [] []`

Comment: This seems to be linked to the method $token->getCredentials() called in authenticateToken method of custom authenticator. Basically, during login, getCredentials() returns password in clear, which is given to the encoder, which returns true(found in db). However, immediately after that, I guess during redirection to /foo/user/secured/target, authenticateToken gets called again. that time, $token->getCredentials() returns empty string, which leads encoder to return false...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: I edited my initial question with step by step identified process. could this help to identify the issue and solve it?

Answer (score 0):

well, as I was not able to make it work fine, I created my own custom authentication provider. I hope the issue reported above will be fixed asap. If anyone has got an answer, I still am interested!

For other people facing the same issue, I recommend creating a custom authentication provider. You may even inherit from existing authentication provider, and therefore limit modifications to be done. All in all, you are able to add your custom logic with a limited amount of trouble that way.